# regex get multiple next line

Tags: regex, iphone

I have questions about regex:

I apologize if my explanation wasn't clear enough.

ex)

Net Cash 
5/7/2018 
Name

I try https://regex101.com/r/fvgaCT/1

but, I want to get the line "**Name**" here

The reason I set the criteria to Net Cash is because "**5/7/2018**"
and "**Name**" are **random values**.

Comment: `(?<=Net Cash [0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ ).+(?=\([^)]+\))`

Comment: 5/7/2018 What should I do for this random character? I want to take the same action as \n\n

Comment: not work https://regex101.com/r/AJG0rC/1

Comment: You changed the question bud, of course it doesn't work!

Comment: Adding newlines actually makes it easier `(?<=Net Cash\n+.*\n+)(.*)(?=\(.*$)` 

Also, try it in regexr, regex101 is bizarre. https://regexr.com/7j6pd

Comment: What is the tool or language? Can you make your question a bit more clear? For example, are there always 2 newlines followed by a date after Net Cash? What is Name? Is that a single word, or all before the parenthesis?

Comment: Checked for regexr operation But I want to know the regex expression method used in iPhone shortcuts

Comment: I apologize if my explanation wasn't clear enough.

ex)
Net Cash
5/7/2018
Name

I want to get the line "Name" here

The reason I set the criteria to Net Cash is because "5/7/2018"
and "Name" are random values.

Comment: @username Please consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question for readability, add the regex that you have tried with the logic for the regex match to the question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I edited the post
I don't know how to wrap lines in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your regex code something like this: `Net Cash \d+/\d+/\d+ (.*)(?=\()`

In python the regex code will look like this:

```py
import re

text = "Net Cash 5/7/2018 Name(Random Text)"
pattern = r"Net Cash \d+/\d+/\d+ (.*)(?=\()"
match = re.search(pattern, text)

if match:
    name = match.group(1)
    print(name)
```

##### output

```
Name
```

`\d+/\d+/\d+` matches a date format like "5/7/2018". `\d+` matches one or more digits, and `/` is a literal character.

`(.*)` captures the text after the date until just before the "(".

`(?=\()` is a positive lookahead assertion to match only up to the "(" without including it in the match.

However if your want to get the full text after the date, you can modify the regex to be `Net Cash \d+/\d+/\d+ (.*)`, something like this:

```py
import re

text = "Net Cash 5/7/2018 Name(Random Text)"
pattern = r"Net Cash \d+/\d+/\d+ (.*)"
match = re.search(pattern, text)

if match:
    name = match.group(1)
    print(name)
```

##### output

```
Name(Random Text)
```

or if you want just want to extract the text right after "Name", you can do that too by modifying the regex to `Net Cash \d+/\d+/\d+ Name(.*)`:

```py
import re

text = "Net Cash 5/7/2018 Name(Random Text)"
pattern = r"Net Cash \d+/\d+/\d+ Name(.*)"
match = re.search(pattern, text)

if match:
    name = match.group(1)
    print(name)
```

##### output

```
(Random Text)
```

Hope it helps :)

## Edit:

Change your regex code to `Net Cash\n.*\n(.*)`
to account for:

```
Net Cash
5/7/2018
Name
```

or change to `(?<=Net Cash\n.{8}\n).*`, though I don't recommend this one.

and get the result: "Name" or any text in place of "Name".

Comment: I edited the question.
I'm trying to use it in iPhone shortcuts

Comment: Oh okay I got it, then you could modify your regex to something like this: `Net Cash\n.*\n(.*)`, to account for

`Net Cash
5/7/2018
Name` to get the result "Name" or any text in place of "Name". I hope it solves your problem. I will update my post too..

Comment: Thank you!
This method works perfectly.

What if the number of characters is 8 or 9?

Comment: Any text with number of characters more or less than 8 in `{8}` will not be accounted, hence this `(?<=Net Cash\n.{8}\n).*` code only works for text with number of characters = 8. You can modify it but it isn't dynamic. That's why I recommend you to use `Net Cash\n.*\n(.*)` method, it uses grouping but it's the best and the most flexible method. If you found my answer helpful please upvote it and mark it as accepted. It will help a lot.

Comment: I tried Net Cash\n.*\n(.*) but I get all the rows.

Comment: That's what I said. It uses grouping, so it matches everything but also adds "Name" to a group which you can access. Matching and grouping can be very handy in some cases. Also it's probably the most flexible solution for your problem.